# find general solution to the Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the differential equation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}= 3x^2 y^2 - y^2
\end{equation}
I get
\begin{equation}
y=6xy^2 + 6x^2 y\frac{dy}{dx} - 2y\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{equation}
rearrange the equation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-6xy^2}{6x^2 y - 2y}
\end{equation}
simplified the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1-6xy}{6x^2 - 2}
\end{equation}

how can I solve this equation to get a general solution of $y=ax+c$

Comment: How do you get the first "equation" you got? Differentiating "dy/dx" with respect to x doesn't give "y".

Comment: i realize my mistake now! thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

You might use separating variable method: you have: $\frac{1}{y^2}dy = (3x^2 -1)dx$, and you integrate both sides to get the answer.

Comment: thanks so much! i get it now =)

Answer (score 1):

HINT :
$$\frac{1}{y^2}dy=(3x^2-1)dx$$
$$-\frac 1y=x^3-x+C$$